# Compare more than 2 (dynamically decide how many list) lists in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object, collections

```
"mainList": [
    {
      "relationship": [
        "cd": "CH",
        "desc": "Child",          
       ],
        "childList": ["A", "B", "C"]
    }, {
     "relationship": [
        "cd": "SPS",
        "desc": "Spouse",
          ],
        "childList": ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
    }, {
      "relationship": [
        "cd": "MBR",
        "desc": "Member",
       ],
        "childList": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
    }, ...
]


public class MainList {
private List<Relationshipsss> relation;
private List<String> childList;

public MainList(List<Relationshipsss> relation, List<String> childList) {
    this.relation = relation;
    this.childList = childList;

}

public List<Relationshipsss> getRelation() {
    return relation;
}

public void setRelation(List<Relationshipsss> relation) {
    this.relation = relation;
}

public List<String> getChildList() {
    return childList;
}

public void setChildList(List<String> childList) {
    this.childList = childList;
}

}

public class ParentList {
private List<MainList> mainList;

public List<MainList> getMainList() {
    return mainList;
}

public void setMainList(List<MainList> mainList) {
    this.mainList = mainList;
}

}
public class Relationshipsss {
private String cd;
private String desc;

public String getCd() {
    return cd;
}
public void setCd(String cd) {
    this.cd = cd;
}
public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}
public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}
}
```

Updated all Entity class. MainList will have relations List and child list.

I want to compare `childList` against each other and take the common and uncommon values and separate like who all it belongs to.

```
Map<String, List<MainList>> result = mainList.stream()
    .flatMap(o -> o.getChildList().stream().map(c -> Map.entry(c, o)))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

Above code is 1st step of your ans. For that i am getting error I mentioned in comment.

Want Output as below:

1. Child, spouse, mbr = A,B,C
2. Spouse, Mbr = D
3. Mbr = E

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: `CollectionUtils.intersection(mainList.get(i).childList(), mainList.get(i+1).childList())
and 
CollectionUtils.subtract(mainList.get(i).childList(), mainList.get(i+1).childList())` getting partial result but not as expected. Getting indexOut of bound with i+1 once the end of list is reached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Java Streams and `Collectors.groupingBy()` solve this:

```
Map<String, List<MainList>> result = mainList.stream()
        .flatMap(o -> o.getChildList().stream().map(c -> Map.entry(c, o)))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

First you `flatMap` all items to an `Entry` with the parent and each child item. Then you group by each child item.

The result of this will be a map grouped by the child items:

```
{
    A: [{relation=[{cd='CH', desc='Child'}], childList=[A, B, C]}, {relation=[{cd='SPS', desc='Spouse'}], childList=[A, B, C, D]}, {relation=[{cd='MBR', desc='Member'}], childList=[A, B, C, D, E]}]
    B: [{relation=[{cd='CH', desc='Child'}], childList=[A, B, C]}, {relation=[{cd='SPS', desc='Spouse'}], childList=[A, B, C, D]}, {relation=[{cd='MBR', desc='Member'}], childList=[A, B, C, D, E]}]
    C: [{relation=[{cd='CH', desc='Child'}], childList=[A, B, C]}, {relation=[{cd='SPS', desc='Spouse'}], childList=[A, B, C, D]}, {relation=[{cd='MBR', desc='Member'}], childList=[A, B, C, D, E]}]
    D: [{relation=[{cd='SPS', desc='Spouse'}], childList=[A, B, C, D]}, {relation=[{cd='MBR', desc='Member'}], childList=[A, B, C, D, E]}]
    E: [{relation=[{cd='MBR', desc='Member'}], childList=[A, B, C, D, E]}]
}
```

After this you can group by your object list again to get a map with all objects as key and a list of your child items:

```
Map<List<MainList>, List<String>> result = mainList.stream()
        .flatMap(o -> o.getChildList().stream().map(c -> Map.entry(c, o)))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));
```

This will result in a map like this:

```
{
    [{relation=[{cd='SPS', desc='Spouse'}], childList=[A, B, C, D]}, {relation=[{cd='MBR', desc='Member'}], childList=[A, B, C, D, E]}]: [D]
    [{relation=[{cd='MBR', desc='Member'}], childList=[A, B, C, D, E]}]: [E]
    [{relation=[{cd='CH', desc='Child'}], childList=[A, B, C]}, {relation=[{cd='SPS', desc='Spouse'}], childList=[A, B, C, D]}, {relation=[{cd='MBR', desc='Member'}], childList=[A, B, C, D, E]}]: [A, B, C]
}
```

The key here is the mapping with `Map.entry(c, o)`. You can replace the value of the entry (`o`) with whatever you need as key of the result. The example above has all the `MainList`s as key. You can use `Map.entry(c, o.getRelation())` if you need a `Map<List<List<Relationshipsss>>, List<String>>`. Or if you need only each first relationship (`Map<List<Relationshipsss>, List<String>>`) use `Map.entry(c, o.getRelation().get(0))`. But be aware of empty lists and maybe use an Optional to wrap this.

If you need the `desc` string for each first relation as key you can use this:

```
Map<List<String>, List<String>> result = parentList.getMainList().stream()
        .flatMap(o -> o.getChildList().stream().map(c -> Map.entry(c, o.getRelation().get(0).getDesc())))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));
```

Bare also in mind the case of an empty relation list. The final result of the last version will be this:

```
{
    [Child, Spouse, Member]: [A, B, C]
    [Spouse, Member]: [D]
    [Member]: [E]
}
```

Comment: What will be the structure of MyObject?

Comment: parent object mean mainList Obj?

Comment: is it possible to achieve this without stream, collectors? I am getting Type mismatch: cannot convert from Stream<Object> to <unknown>

Comment: `Map<List<String>, List<String>> result = mainList.stream()
              .flatMap(o -> o.getChildList().stream().map(c -> Map.entry(c, o.getRelationship().get(0).getDesc())))
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())))
              .entrySet().stream()
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));`                                        for this also getting Type mismatch: cannot convert from Stream<Object> to <unknown>

Comment: Updated relation class